# Alternative source for Vertibird Signal Grenades?

Tags: fallout-4

I can't buy Vertibird Signal Grenades from my initial source anymore. Is there an alternate source? If so, how do I access them?

> I've heard that Tinker Tom will start selling them. When does this happen?

Comment: While some users might consider that a spoiler, it is the focus of your question. As such, [it is not an appropriate use of spoiler tags](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9806/is-editing-a-question-to-use-the-spoiler-format-acceptable). "Here's the golden rule: The question and the answers must make sense and be complete without using spoiler tags. Even if the spoiler is a major one, it should not be protected if that's the very piece of spoiler the question is about. Feel free to spoiler protect things, but if you don't heed the golden rule, you are doing it wrong."

Comment: I also feel we do not need to know backstory of the item to tell you when a particular NPC will be able to sell them to you, and since this backstory was the main spoiler, I have simply removed it.

Comment: I hope it is ok to provide links-I found this site helpful-http://attackofthefanboy.com/guides/fallout-4-guide-get-artillery-smoke-grenades/

Comment: Pretty sure you need to complete the whole Railroad questline.

Comment: Wow, what a spoiler. Edited the question to hopefully tuck it a bit further away, while retaining the original intent and meaning. I get that the answers will inherently be spoilerific, but the question in its Rev 2 state seemed just a bit unnecessarily so.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vertibird_signal_grenade, he starts providing them after you complete the Railroad main questline. So probably after you finish the Nuclear Option for the Railroad.

> Vertibirds still appear after the BoS has been defeated.

Comment: "Brotherhood of Steel, the Minutemen, or the Railroad upon completion of the former's main questline" – I'd think that "the former" would mean the Minutemen in this case (Railroad would be "the latter"), but it isn't unreasonable that the conditions are the same for the two factions

Comment: "from Tinker Tom at the Railroad HQ after finishing the main questline for the Railroad. "
What were you quoting from?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm a bit late, but it turns out, it works the same as artillery grenades. Simply go to the workshop and look in the weapons tab. They should show up. (I did minutemen, by the way.) Hope this helps. Not sure if it will work for Railroad, but I hope it will.

Answer (score -5):

Basically you don’t have to do anything to get them, you just have to pick them up. You see, wherever you make an artillery station and assign a worker (see the guide linked above for details) you’ll begin generating more artillery smoke grenades. You should build plenty of these, as their range is limited, making it so having one at each of your settlements is the wisest option. Just be sure you’ve established supply lines between all of your settlements and you should have enough resources for the job.

Give it some time and swing back by your settlements and they’ll have extra artillery smoke grenades waiting for you. They’ll be in the Workshop inventory, so head to the station and hit the Transfer button to check out all that it has available. If you’ve let enough time pass, which should be about three in-game days, then there will be more artillery smoke grenades for you to enjoy.

The Castle is a bit different though, as it will also respawn artillery smoke grenades in the box where you originally got them in the first place. Head back to the armory inside of the Castle to find them. After a while you can probably skip this though, as your various artillery stations will produce plenty of grenades, unless you’re really going crazy out there in the Fallout 4 wasteland.

Comment: But the question is about calling Vertibird, not artillery support